# facebook app gives Call to a member function api() on a non-object error

Tags: php, facebook

i have an app on facebook that's giving me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object in 
/public_html/user/fbmin.php on line 7
```

here's the code:

```
  try{             //here's line 7:
        $userdata= $facebook->api('/me');
        //request for user friends in app
        $frienddata=$facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
 ));}

catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$userdata = null;
$frienddata= null;
}
```

the odd thing is that i use this same code on another page and everything works fine, i've tried making $facebook global by writing

```
GLOBAL $facebook;
```

before the try statement, still it gives the same error, what could be the problem?

Comment: paste var_dump($facebook) and code where you created this oject

Comment: i can't access the page now, facebook says:The page you requested was not found
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.
Return home
Go back to the previous page is there a way to solve this? it's now even affecting my other pages as well!

Comment: When working with cross-site auth like this, clear your cookies often; that's my best guess from this far away.

Comment: i even tried adding p3p headers, still the problem persists, is this because it's an iframe app? would this problem exist if i changed it to a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that `$facebook` is not yet initialized. In the other files (which work), look for a line like this:

```
$facebook = ...
```

And you need that stuff in this file, too. Or perhaps there is a dedicated fb initialization file that you need to include.

Comment: i have done so, i've included a file that was in the other pages but now, whenever i try to access this page, facebook says: page not found

Comment: But we are initializing $facebook variable again. With the credentials etc. Is that the way?

Comment: @RicardoGonzales I think the original issue was that on this particular request, the $facebook variable was not initialized the first time, so there is no 'again' in the context of this request. With respect to being "DRY", then the advice is to `include` the file with the initialization.